# Setting a variable for lineEdits

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

This is my first post and  my question will probably seem fairly simple to most of you obviously not to a beginner like myself.
In short I have different spinboxes and comboboxes which update lineEdits ie:

```
if ZpSpin == 0 and AntiIce == ON and ToSpin == 25000:
    self.V1lineEdit.setText((str(100)))
    self.VRlineEdit.setText((str(104)))
    self.V2lineEdit.setText((str(108)))
```

Obviously there will be lots of if/elif and every time I will have to set different lineEdits.
Can I set a variable for the lineEdits where by I could just write?:

```
if ZpSpin == 0 and AntiIce == ON and ToSpin == 25000:
    V1 = (100)
    VR = (104)
    V2 = (108)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make objects of the functions

```
v1 = self.V1lineEdit.setText
vR = self.VRlineEdit.setText
v3 = self.V2lineEdit.setText
```

then call them.

```
v1('100')
vR('104')
v1('108')

print v1  #<bound method somclass.somemethod of <__main__.someclass instance at 0x7fcfd8556758>
```